# Python scripting in ABAQUS

Tags: python, string, scripting, abaqus, objectname

I  have a python script to create ABAQUS model and run a job.

I want to create a loop over a variable

index=1:1:4,

create four different models and run the four jobs for each model.

A model is named 'Model-1' for instance in the following line:

```
##-----------------------------------------------------------------------
mdb.models['Model-1'].ConstrainedSketch(name='__profile__', sheetSize=sqrlen) 
##-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In creating a loop, I create a string as follows:

```
##-----------------------------------------------------------------------
index='1'
modelname='\''+'Model' + index+ '\'' 

# Square Part is created
mdb.models[modelname].ConstrainedSketch(name='__profile__', sheetSize=sqrlen)
##-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I run the script in ABAQUS, it gives error saying 'Model1'as follows:

```
##------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

  File "d:/abaqus_working_directory/scripting_example/simulation/scripting_loop.py", line 22, in <module>
    mdb.models[modelname].ConstrainedSketch(name='__profile__', sheetSize=sqrlen)  #### sqrlen
KeyError: 'Model1'
Exit from main file  [Kernel]: d:/abaqus_working_directory/scripting_example/simulation/scripting_loop.py
##-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to use the string modelname( with value ='Model-1') instead of writing 'Model-1' in the python script

```
mdb.models['Model-1'].ConstrainedSketch(name=....)
mdb.models[modelname].ConstrainedSketch(name=...)
```

when it is called.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Sincerely,
Me.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing two different names, `Model-1` and `Model1`

In your loop creation, include `-` in the `modelname`. You can do something like this:

```
##-----------------------------------------------------------------------
index='1'
modelname='\''+'Model-' + index+ '\'' 

# Square Part is created
mdb.models[modelname].ConstrainedSketch(name='__profile__', sheetSize=sqrlen)
##-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Also, you should use

```
modelname='Model-' + index
```

since that will give you a string without the extra quotes.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Modelname can be anything like 'Square', 'Trapezium-Model' etc... The basic question is how to code the string Modelname so that python can read :  mdb.model[modelname].Constrained~~~. etc as mdb.model['Square'].Constrained~~~

Comment: @gama I think you missed the point.  Your name can not be "anything", it has to be a name that exists and you need to spell it exactly right including a hyphen as needed.

Answer (score 1):

don't work with the string names at all. Early in the script define:

```
 model=mdb.models['Model-1']
```

then do for example:

```
 model.ConstrainedSketch..
```

if you are working with multiple models then similarly create a list of model objects.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I solved it in June First week.